# Can I execute ipython scripts?

Tags: python, ipython

Is there a way to execute ipython scripts? I don't mean python scripts, but with simplified syntax as it would be entered into the ipython shell

Answer (score 14, accepted):

sure, just run them with IPython as you with Python for a plain Python script:

```
$> echo '%time print "hello, world"' > script.ipy
$> ipython script.ipy
hello, world
CPU times: user 0.00 s, sys: 0.00 s, total: 0.00 s
Wall time: 0.00 s
```

Comment: The key is the `.ipy` extension, otherwise it will try to run it as a plain python file.

Comment: The `$>` confused me at first. Then I deduced it's the OS shell prompt.