# Bash cell magic in IPython script

Tags: bash, ipython

This is my first post on SO, so please let me know if the problem is not well defined. I have a script **process.ipy** in which I am trying to implement a cell magic as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython

%%bash
ls
```

When I run this on the command line (Ubuntu and zsh shell), I get the following error,

```
$ ipython process.ipy                                                                                                 
File "<ipython-input-1-f108be8d32f2>", line 3
  %%bash
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, I can run this in the ipython session without a problem,

```
In [1]: %%bash
   ...: ls
   ...: 
process.ipy
```

More confusing, is that the single line version works in the script,

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython

!ls
```

What am I doing wrong? Is something not setup correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the #!/usr/bin/env ipython line at the top.
The error :

```
%%bash
ls
```

Comment: Thanks, what made it work is the newline between the `%%bash` magic to the actual command(s).

Answer (score 5):

Short Answer: magic commands are understood only in an IPython interactive session, not in scripts.

Longer Answer: they can be called in scripts, but only using a library call, not the `%%` notation as described in [How to run an IPython magic from a script (or timing a Python script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361206/how-to-run-an-ipython-magic-from-a-script-or-timing-a-python-script). Note that the mechanism is IPython version dependent.

Comment: I guess I didn't read that post well enough. Will keep this in mind. gmk's suggestion seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `#!/usr/bin/env ipython` line at the top.
The cell magic should be first line in the cell.

just try the following and it should work

```
%%bash
ls
```