# How do I define custom magics in jupyter?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` with an Anaconda python installation:

> Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)

I'm trying to use [this recipe](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rossant/ipython-minibook/blob/master/chapter6/602-cpp.ipynb) to enable C++ interactive compiling in my ipython notebooks:

```
import IPython.core.magic as ipym

@ipym.magics_class
class CppMagics(ipym.Magics):
    @ipym.cell_magic
    def cpp(self, line, cell=None):
        """Compile, execute C++ code, and return the standard output."""
        # Define the source and executable filenames.
        source_filename = 'temp.cpp'
        program_filename = 'temp.exe'
        # Write the code contained in the cell to the C++ file.
        with open(source_filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(cell)
        # Compile the C++ code into an executable.
        compile = self.shell.getoutput("g++ {0:s} -o {1:s}".format(
            source_filename, program_filename))
        # Execute the executable and return the output.
        output = self.shell.getoutput(program_filename)
        return output

def load_ipython_extension(ipython):
    ipython.register_magics(CppMagics)
```

Whether I fire up my notebook with `ipython notebok` or `jupyter notebook` (I believe the first aliases to the second anyway), when I execute a cell with :

```
%load_ext cppmagic
```

I get the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7b90c7a2b808> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic('load_ext cppmagic')

/home/norah/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in magic(self, arg_s)
   2334         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2335         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2336         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2337 
   2338     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/norah/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2255                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2256             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2257                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2258             return result
   2259 

/home/norah/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.py in load_ext(self, module_str)

/home/norah/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/home/norah/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.py in load_ext(self, module_str)
     64         if not module_str:
     65             raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
---> 66         res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
     67 
     68         if res == 'already loaded':

/home/norah/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.py in load_extension(self, module_str)
     87             if module_str not in sys.modules:
     88                 with prepended_to_syspath(self.ipython_extension_dir):
---> 89                     __import__(module_str)
     90             mod = sys.modules[module_str]
     91             if self._call_load_ipython_extension(mod):

ImportError: No module named 'cppmagic'
```

The code in the recipe seems to agree with [the official docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/custommagics.html#defining-magics) (both use `IPython.core.magic.magics_class`) I have placed my `cppmagic.py` in the following directory

> ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup

to have it autoload on notebook startup, but I can't get feel the magic. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two separate things here:

1. **startup files** are *scripts* in `~/.ipython/profile_[name]/startup` that are executed as part of starting IPython. They are treated as if you `%run` each of them prior to the first `In[1]` prompt. Startup files cannot be imported, because they are not on `sys.path`.
2. **extensions** are Python modules that can be imported and define a `load_ipython_extension` function. You can put extensions in `~/.ipython/extensions` and they will be importable, or you can install them as regular packages with `pip`.

The first fix is to move your `cppmagics` to `~/.ipython/extensions` or to some `site-packages` directory, so that it is importable.

If you really want the magics always registered (rather than calling `%load_ext cppmagic`), you can leave it as a startup file and register the magic at the end of the script, instead of `def load_ipython_extension`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from IPython import get_ipython
    get_ipython().register_magics(CppMagics)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works! The recipe unfortunately doesn't .... I get a `['/bin/sh: 1: temp.exe: not found']` error, but that has to do with the recipe code itself. I'm selecting this answer, if you could help with my last issue I'd appriaciate it.

Comment: You might want to add a `./temp.exe` to ensure it's looking in the local dir, I'm not sure.