# %edit magic command not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I can't work out how to get the %edit command working in Jupyter Notebook.

I type

```
%edit
```

and it returns with

```
IPython will make a temporary file named: /var/folders/dk/.../ipython_edit_JbS9ZC.py
```

My %EDITOR environment variable is

```
'EDITOR': '/usr/local/bin/subl -w'
```

I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem ! It works perfectly in the IPython shell though

Comment: Have you tried to "control the editor by setting TerminalInteractiveShell.editor in ipython_config.py" (https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/editors.html) after creating a profile (https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html) ?

Comment: It also works in the iPython shell for me. I am a little confused about how to configure Jupyter (http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) but I think the setting should go elsewhere. However, if I set it using '%config InteractiveShell.editor = 'nano'' and use '%env', I get ''EDITOR': 'nano'', and it still doesn't work. Is %edit supposed to work in the jupyter notebook?

Comment: I really don't know, I have exactly the same problem !

Answer (score 1):

This feature issue appears to be well-known : https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5879

A possible solution might be to use : [Edit IPython cell in an external editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309430/edit-ipython-cell-in-an-external-editor)

Or you can embed the notebook in emacs (I don't use emacs) : https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook

Comment: plus-1 for *feature issue* instead of *bug*