# Is there a way to run `%memit` inside a script without wrapping it in iphyton

Tags: python, sage, memory-profiling, ipython-magic

I am logging the RAM usage of `sagemath` commands against each other and want to automate it

I found `%memit` and I found information on wrapping each [command][[How to run an IPython magic from a script (or timing a Python script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361206/how-to-run-an-ipython-magic-from-a-script-or-timing-a-python-script]) but that is not ideal

```py
from sage.all_cmdline import *   # import sage library
from sage.misc.sage_timeit import sage_timeit

from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()

if '__IPYTHON__' in globals():
            ipython.magic('load_ext autoreload')
            ipython.magic('load_ext memory_profiler')

ipython.magic("TIME=%timeit -o print 'test'")
```

```
ipython.magic("TIME=%timeit -o print 'test'")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'magic'
```

Is there a better way to use `memit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the memory-profiler manual: https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/

For instance, it supplies a decorator for profiling functions, which might suit your needs:

```
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def my_func():
    a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
    del b
    return a

my_func()
```

You could also use the command line interface:

`python -m memory_profiler example.py`

The manual describes several other ways of invoking it...