# Run ipython as a non-interactive script

Tags: python, ipython

Is it possible to run a script that uses ipython-specific functionality (non-python)?

I am considering ipython as an extension of python here, since it supports things like bang (`!`) and magic (`%`, `%%`) commands.

Therefore my question is that if it's possible to have something like an `.ipy` script file that is written in the "ipython language" and that I can run non-interactively, like I would do with a normal python script (`python script.py`).

A simple example of what I would like to achieve:

```py
# valid ipython code
files = !ls
print(files)
```

(that is my `ls.ipy`)

run it like:

```sh
python ls.ipy
# output: list of files in this directory
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10361206/7954504 may be helpful

Comment: thanks! I had a look there an at [jupyter's nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). Unfortunately in the question you linked all solutions write in python (not ipython as I am intending it here) and import the `IPython` library and make use of it. I think I found a way just now, playing around a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your shell:

```sh
ipython ls.ipy
```

Comment: Ops, just found out I can do that by trial and error and self-answered. Is this documented in the ipython documentation? (I'm sure it is but I didn't find it)

Comment: `ipython --help` provides the usage with file as an argument.

Comment: Thanks! But do you know if it's well documented somewhere in the [official documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). I think this feature ("ipython as a scripting language") is very useful (it makes me want to use this instead of bash scripts on my system) and should be more visible. (Although I recognize that the whole point of "I"python is the "I"nteractivity. But still, I'm pretty excited about this alternative usage!)

Comment: I don't see it either. You can improve the documentation [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/2922831acf6d7c185fb863b4436ffd7cfa665675/docs/source/interactive/tutorial.rst)

Answer (score 0):

Playing around a bit I just found a way:

`ipython myscript.ipy`

with `myscript.ipy` written in "ipython" (it's not a jupyter notebook, it's not a python script that imports `IPython`, but it's a python + bang `!` and magic `%` syntax). For example:

```py
files = !ls
print(files)
```

or

```py
a = 1
%whos
```