# Call Jupyter Notebook magic command programmatically, from script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

You can [call a magic command in Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361206/how-to-run-an-ipython-magic-from-a-script-or-timing-a-python-script) from a script as follows:

```
ipython = get_ipython()
mgc = ipython.run_line_magic

mgc(magic_name = "my_magic_command", line="line_to_call")
```

But if I try to do this with the HTML magic command:

```
mgc(magic_name = "%%html", line="<iframe src='my_url' width='100%' height='400'></iframe>")
```

I get the following error:

```
UsageError: Line magic function `%%%html` not found.
```

Makes me think I should remove one of the %:

```
mgc(magic_name = "%html", line="<iframe src='my_url' width='100%' height='400'>")

UsageError: Line magic function `%%html` not found.
```

...or remove both %:

```
mgc(magic_name = "html", line="<iframe src='my_url' width='100%' height='400'>")

UsageError: Line magic function `%html` not found (But cell magic `%%html` exists, did you mean that instead?).
```

This might have something to do with the [order of imports](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5269), but I cannot seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite instructive:

```
UsageError: Line magic function `%html` not found
(But cell magic `%%html` exists, did you mean that instead?).
```

There's a difference between "line magic" and "cell magic" functions. Let's use the `run_cell_magic()` function:

```
ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.run_cell_magic("html", "", "<iframe src='https://stackoverflow.com' width='100%' height='400'></iframe>")
```

The first parameter is the cell magic function name without the leading `%%`, the second parameter is the rest of the first line (we leave it empty), the third parameter is the HTML snipped you wish to show.

For details refer to [the IPython documentation of run_cell_magic()](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html?highlight=run_cell_magic#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.run_cell_magic).